# using 1136 x 640 images in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uistoryboard

EDIT: Dont misunderstand. I get that I can put in `myImage.png` whose size is 568 x 320 and `myImage@2x.png` whose size is 1136 X 640 and, at run time, iOS will show the lager image if the device has a retina screen. That is not what this is about. Im talking strictly about placing a 1136 x 640 image in the storyboard.

Some details:

- Using xcode 5
- iPhone only app (iPhone 4 and above ideally)
- Targeting iOS 7 (should keep out any iPhone 3gs ...right?)
- Single view app
- Using storyboards

My understanding is that I can provide only the higher resolution 1136 x 640 images my app needs for the iPhone 5 then use autolayout to constrain things in such a way that my UI works properly even if the device is an iPhone 4 and has less screen real estate.

My issue is that if I drag a 1136 x 640 image onto the storyboard the image is 2X the size of the view im dropping it into. I get that I can resize the UIImageView and set the mode to aspect fit and the image will display correctly in the view.

However, that would get quite annoying. Is there a way to just set the storyboard to use the retina images directly?

Now I can create images that are half the size (568 x 320) and those will drag and drop into the views perfectly. But I cant imagine why anyone would want to do that. This doesnt make sense to me. I would expect the SDK to let me layout the app in the highest resolution possible.

I tried using images named `myImage.png` and using `myImage@2x.png` but neither changed anything.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think of the dimensions in Xcode as pixels, but points. So while you set the image dimensions to be 568 x 320, the @2x images are going to use two pixels per point.

What are you testing on? You might not be seeing a difference because you are only testing on retina devices. If you are only planning on supporting iOS 7 (iPhone 4 and up), you won't be using any non-retina devices.

Comment: Yeah I get the points part but are you saying then that my images should only be 568 X 320?  See my edit above, I added pictures of what im talking about

Comment: When you are laying out the images in your views, the size refers to how they will actually map to the screen. 320 x 480 for iPhone 4/4s and 320 x 568 for iPhone 5/5s. Your image is larger than the view because you are telling it to fill up a space larger than the screen. So setup your images with dimensions you want on screen and then provide retina images (@2x) that are double those dimensions in pixels. Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html) to clarify.

Comment: Ok, so basically what you are saying is "No, you cant drag and drop retina images directly into the UIViews in the storyboard. Youd have drag and drop the image then manually change the UIImageView to be no more than 320 x 568 and set the UIImageView to aspect fit."  What was throwing me off is that (i get the points to pixels thing) but since all iOS7 devices ARE retina i would think that setting the build to iOS7, one could drop the retina images into the storyboard and xcode would just understand that the 640 x 1136 "pixel" image should fill the 320 x 568 "points" view.  Maybe in 6.0...

Comment: Yes to your first question; make the UIImage size half of the actual image dimensions. Since you are only supporting iOS 7 & iPhones, you only have to supply '@2x' images. Just as an FYI, there are two devices that support iOS 7 that are not retina: iPad 2 & iPad Mini. Even though your app will be iPhone only, iPad users can install it. But with iOS 7, the 1x/2x size toggle is removed for the non-retina iPads and they automatically use the '@2x' images.